# Python, calculation of non-overlapping AVAR

Tags: python, math

It was a bit tough to find an appropriate title for this question. I need to calculate the expression underneath with various values of `M` using Python.

σ(M) <sup>2</sup> = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2 (M−1)</sub> ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>M−1</sup> [y<sub>i+1</sub> − y<sub>i</sub>] <sup>2</sup>

(LaTeX `$\sigma(M)^2 = \frac{1}{2(M-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} [y_{i+1}-y_{i}]^2$`)

(for the curious mind, this is the non-overlapping Allan Deviation)

```
y = [a,a1,a2,a3,a4, ... ]
tau = p.linspace(1, len(y), len(y))
M = tau
```

Where `a_i` are just values for example `a=1.02`, `a1=2.34`, `a2=8.94` and so on.
I am very unsure on how to do this but I'm guessing something like a for-loop within a for-loop. Where the inner loop makes the sum and the outer loop loops over the 'σ's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
for Mvalue in M:
#iterate over all values
    result=0.0
    for i in range(1,int(Mvalue)):
        #calculate the sum (**2 is squared in python)
        result=result+(y[i+1]-y[i])**2
    #divide result
    result=result/(2*(Mvalue-1))
    print result
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat right. But I am getting an error... "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: @Nillo I think i fixed it. If it still doesn't work, tell me which line and I'll check it out

Comment: @Nillo yep, works now, but be careful with the linspace. If M is 1 at some point you divide by zero.

Comment: I think that fixes it yes. But I think something else in my code is causing me errors now. Thanks a lot for your help you have givin me something to work with.